# infer and type literals giving build errors

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a component NPM package and for handling the MDI icon names dynamically from a library that I use I've written the following type helpers to assist in extracting the names in a union type.

The issue is that when I do `npm run build` the compiler an error message about not being able to compile the types, and says there is a syntax issue.

When I comment out the following lines and run the build again, and uncomment and run the build again, it works without any errors.

```
export type StripPrefix<
  T extends string,
  Prefix extends string
> = T extends `${Prefix}${infer R}` ? R : never;

export type CamelToHyphen<T extends string> = T extends `${infer L}${infer R}`
  ? `${L extends Capitalize<L>
      ? `-${Uncapitalize<L>}`
      : Uncapitalize<L>}${CamelToHyphen<R>}`
  : "";
```

These helpers are used in my code like this:

```
import * as Path from "@mdi/js";
import { CamelToHyphen, StripPrefix } from "../../helpers/type-helpers";


type MdiIcons = keyof typeof Path;

type HyphenatedIcon<T extends string, Prefix extends string> = CamelToHyphen<
  StripPrefix<T, Prefix>
> extends `-${infer R}`
  ? R
  : "";

export type Icons = HyphenatedIcon<MdiIcons, "mdi">;
```

I've tried a lot of things, including updating Babel config and plugins, but I can't seem to figure out why this issue is ongoing. I've noticed it has maybe something to do with Babel not being able to handle template literal types properly, but even after adding plugin support I still get the same issue when building.

Comment: **Needs debugging details** 
The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.